# Reset OpenStack admin password

Tags: passwords, openstack, keystone, horizon

I have installed openstack on my VM. I changed my admin password but I do not know it(I have generated via keepass, but forget to save it :( )

Now I want to change it.

```
stack@smaug:~/devstack$ openstack user password set --password somepassword admin
Could not recognize Fernet token (HTTP 404) (Request-ID: req-8ba5e9a3-f8df-4ef1-91ab-24e6da33ff8f)
```

Could you help me How to use Fernet token and How Can I change admin password?

## Solved, Update:

```
source /opt/stack/devstack/openrc admin admin
openstack user set --password-prompt admin
```

Now I am able to login \o/